# Javascript: Function does not get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have somehow a beginner's question about the following structure:

```
<body>


<p id="text_object">Some text</p>

<button id="button_change_text">change text on click</button>



// Individual script on page template
// ----------------------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
   var object = $('#text_object');
   changeTextOnLoad(object);
</script>

// Footer from included footer.php with universal main.js file
// ------------------------------------------------------------
<footer>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
</footer>

</body>
```

My **main.js** contains the following:

```
// declaration of function for writing new text into text object on load
function changeTextOnLoad(object) {
    object.text('New text');
}

// declaration of click function
$('#button_change_text').on('click', function() {
   $('#text_object').text('New text');
});
```

**My problem:** My console tells me that changeTextOnLoad() is undefined. But clicking on the button and changing the text by this way works perfectly fine. Where is the reason? *Why in my main.js file does the click function get fired but not the changeTextOnLoad function?*

Comment: because you call the function before your main.js file has loaded, put your main.js include before the script that executes changeTextOnload, or put the call in an onload event like window.onload

Comment: is it possible to put the entire main.js in an onload event? how do i do that?

Comment: why dont you use document.ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your changeTextOnLoad function before the main.js file has loaded. Either put the function call in an onload event callback or put the include above the call

```
window.onload = function(){
   var object = $('#text_object');
   changeTextOnLoad(object);
};
//Or using addEventListener
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   var object = $('#text_object');
   changeTextOnLoad(object);
});
//Or since you are using jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
   var object = $('#text_object');
   changeTextOnLoad(object);
});
//Or
$(function(){
   var object = $('#text_object');
   changeTextOnLoad(object);
});
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object = $('#text_object');
    changeTextOnLoad(object);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

because main.js is another file, browser takes time to download it. But you run `changeTextOnLoad(object);`  before that.